# How do I split a file into multiline chunks on the empty lines in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, split, ldap

I'm trying to transform the output of an LDAP search into an Authors file for a Git/SVN migration.

I have the output from an `ldapsearch` command. The line endings and empty lines are line feeds (`LF`). I want to split the file into chunks for further processing within each `dn` record (the multiline chunk between each empty line).

```
dn: cn=alice,ou=users,dc=foo
cn: alice
givenName: Alice
email: alice@foo.com

dn: cn=bob,ou=users,dc=foo
cn: bob
givenName: Bob
email: bob@foo.com

dn: cn=carol,ou=users,dc=foo
cn: carol
givenName: Carol
email: carol@foo.com
```

I prefer PowerShell's text manipulation capabilities because I'm a linux-novice. I thought I could use the `-split` operator and multiple linefeeds `` `n `` to indicate the empty line. For the sake of testing it, I select just the first "chunk".

```
PS> (Get-Content ldapsearch.txt) -split "`n`n" | Select-Object -First 1
dn: cn=alice,ou=users,dc=foo
```

However, no matter how I structure the split, I always get the very first line and nothing else! I've tried all sorts of regex split values and options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another example of not understanding `Get-Content`. It's reading the file in line-by-line and stripping newlines. So, there are not multiple newlines to read or split on.

You have to pass `-Raw`

```
PS> (Get-Content ldapsearch.txt -Raw) -split "`n`n" | Select-Object -First 1
dn: cn=alice,ou=users,dc=foo
cn: alice
givenName: Alice
email: alice@foo.com
```

Or use `| Out-String` to put it back together.

```
PS> $search = Get-Content ldapsearch.txt | Out-String 
PS> $search -split "`n`n" | Select-Object -First 1
dn: cn=alice,ou=users,dc=foo
cn: alice
givenName: Alice
email: alice@foo.com
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847788.aspx

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell:

```
$string = Get-Content "file.txt" | Out-String
$nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine
$items = ($string -split "$nl$nl")
```

Should work (assuming CR+LF line breaks and that empty lines are actually empty).

And since you mentioned Linux, example in Python:

```
file_name = "file.txt"
with open(file_name, 'r') as open_file:
    txt = open_file.read()
    items = txt.split('\r\n\r\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a custom “double newline” delimiter to Get-Content.

```
$d="

"
Get-Content -Path demo.txt -Delimiter $d
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content

Comment: Please add an explanation with your code.  It makes it much easier to understand and remember that the aim is not only to help people solve their problem but also tell them why and where they went wrong.

Comment: it's my version split empty lines and my first answer on this site

Answer (score 0):

other solution with Template

```
$template=@"
{elementdn*:dn: cn=name1,ou=users1,dc=foo1}
cn: name1
givenName: givenName1
email: email1

{elementdn*:dn: cn=name2,ou=users2,dc=foo2}
cn: name2
givenName: givenName2
email: email2
"@


Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template
```

if you want all data

```
$template=@"
dn: {dn*:cn=name1,ou=users1,dc=foo1}
cn: {cn:name1}
givenName: {givenName:givenName1}
email: {email:email1}

dn: {dn*:cn=name2,ou=users2,dc=foo2}
cn: {cn:name2}
givenName: {givenName:givenName2}
email: {email:email@}
"@


Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```